# ¿Cómo quitar la advertencia de que falta "key" prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Tengo el componente React llamado Event donde se carga cierta información de los eventos guardados en una base de datos. Como pueden ver le paso su "key" pero en la consola del navegador aparece la advertencia, Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop, en el primer componente generado. No afecta nada en la funcionalidad de mi codigo, pero quisiera saber como quitar esa advertencia.

```
export const Aside = ({events}: Props) => {
    return (
        <aside>
            <div className="events">
                <strong className="head_event">Upcoming events</strong>
                {events.map((event)=>{
                    return <Event event={event} key={event._id}/>
                })}
            </div>    
        </aside>
    )
```

[image: Advertencia de React]

Comment: Puede que realmente no lo necesites, pero ¿leíste en la documentación oficial [por qué React necesita keys?](https://es.react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#why-does-react-need-keys)

Answer (score 0):

el key es importante para que React funcione correctamente, mejor revisa que la propiedad `_id` exista correctamente y no se repita, por último usa el index del map si es que la posición de los elementos va a ser la misma siempre, pero no es muy recomendado.

Answer (score 0):

Ante todo quiero aclarar que soy nuevo en React (unos 3 meses aprox.) pero doy con gusto mi opinión y que esta pueda aportar a la comunidad, y si en dado caso mi respuesta no es la correcta, por favor ayúdenme a corregir.

Viendo tu código y por el tiempo que llevo practicando React, yo entiendo que la 'key' debe asignarse a un elemento dentro del componente y no al componente en sí.

Por lo cual tu Componente  podría quedar estructurado de la siguiente manera:

```
export default function Event({events}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {events.map((event)=>(
          <li key={event._id}>
            {/* Tu código... */}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

En este caso el elemento 'li' es el que estará repitiéndose constantemente con tus multiples Eventos, y por tanto, es quien debería llevar el 'id'.

Espero me haya explicado bien y que mi respuesta te pueda ayudar.

Saludos :)